# Strange outputs of %g in printf

Tags: c, printf

As I know, the conversion rules of `%g` in `printf` are that using `%e` or `%E` if the exponent is less than `-4` or greater than or equal to the precision; otherwise use `%f`. Trailing zeros and a trailing decimal point are not printed.

However, the outputs of below is very strange:

```
printf("%g %G\n", 10.123456789, 10.12345); // output: 10.1235 10.1235
```

Because the precision of `%g` is 6, I guess it would outputs `1.012346e+01`, but it doesn't. Who can help me understand this?

Comment: ...`printf("%g %E\n`...)...

Comment: Read the official documentation of printf

Comment: @l'L'l What do you means?

Comment: What is _very strange_ about `output: 10.1235 10.1235`?

Comment: @kameiha: You should be able to use `e`, or `E`... while selecting the precision (eg. `printf("%.2e %.23E\n")`) ... my first comment I accidentally left `g` in there... meant `e`.

Answer (score 3):

From [this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

> Let P equal the precision if nonzero, 6 if the precision is not specified, or 1 if the precision is ​0​. Then, if a conversion with style E would have an exponent of X:
>
> - if P > X ≥ −4, the conversion is with style f or F and precision P − 1 − X.
> - otherwise, the conversion is with style e or E and precision P − 1.

Since you use the default precision then `P` is equal to `6`. The exponent `X` is `1`. That means `P > X ≥ −4` is true (`6 > 1 ≥ −4`) and the output is printed with the `f` (or `F`) specifier and the precision `6 - 1 - 1` (which is equal to `4` and is the precision you see).

In short, the output is actually what it should be.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood `%g` before.